# Ideas for the matrix

Tags: java, matrix

I have a question about an assignment. I need to create matrix where I will put some robots(that is not important, Robot is another class and an objects of that class I need to put on some positions in matrix). The problem is that matrix fields can be "water" and "land". So how I can keep information about robots and "water" or "land" in same field of matrix.

I try this:

```
HashMap[][] field = new HashMap[15][25];
  Robot robot[];

  Robovil(){

    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < 25; j++){
        field[i][j] = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         if(j % 2 == 0)
          field[i][j].put("land", new Object());
         else
          field[i][j].put("water", new Object()); 
      }
    }
```

but I get this message from compiler:

> Warning: unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type
>   java.util.Map

Does anyone have a better idea???

Comment: Why isn't Neo in the question?

Comment: hahaha to avoid some misunderstood :)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps create an `Enum` named Land and have contain Water and Ground and use an matrix of type `Land` then have another matrix in parallel for the `Robot`s

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

**Edit:** Create a new class and call it say `Tile`. Give it two fields, one for the `Land` and the other for the `Robot`. Then create a matrix out of `Tile`s

Comment: But I need in same field put Land and Robot. One possibility is create two matrix, one for Land, one for Robots, but that is easy way :)

Comment: so simple, well done. that is useful, I can use that, but I'd love to hear more suggestions